# Proof of the cube root trick

Tags: elementary-number-theory, roots

***I'm wondering about the cube root trick:***

To find a cube root of a large number, you only have to memorize the cube roots of numbers 1 to 10.

Take the last digit of your number, it'll be the last digit of the result.

then ignore the last 3 digits, look at what remains, and find which of the first 10 cubes is the closest to it without going over.

No put the result together.

Example: $\sqrt[3]{39304} = 34$ because last digit of 39304 is 4 and $3^3 =  27$ is closest cube to 39.

**How can you proof that this trick works?**

[image]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How can you proof that this trick works?

Comment: So the cube root of $39302$ is $32$?

Comment: It only works if your given number is a cube of a two-digit number. Of course, if you can work out the first digit and last digit of a two digit number, then you have the whole two-digit number.

Comment: That meme doesn't work for integers much greater than one million.

Comment: It's not that simple: the cubes of numbers ending with $2, 3, 7, 8$ end with $8, 7, 3, 2$, respectively. So your recipe is wrong as written, and of very limited use even in corrected form.

Answer (score 3):

If you only look at the last digit (modulo $10$), you have the pattern: 
$$0^3\equiv_{10}0$$
$$1^3\equiv_{10}1$$
$$2^3\equiv_{10}8$$
$$3^3\equiv_{10}7$$
$$4^3\equiv_{10}4$$
$$5^3\equiv_{10}5$$
$$6^3\equiv_{10}6$$
$$7^3\equiv_{10}3$$
$$8^3\equiv_{10}2$$
$$9^3\equiv_{10}1$$

For instance, $\sqrt[3]{140608}=52$, since $5^3<140<6^3$, and the last digit $8$ corresponds to the $2$ (see pattern). The reason why you don't have to think about the three last digits is because $$(a\cdot 10+b)^3=a^3\cdot 1000+3a^2b\cdot 100+3ab^2\cdot 10+b^3$$ So the first three digits is greater than $a^3$ (which means that this method would become hard to use for large numbers). This only works when you know that the number you're given is a perfect cube.

Comment: How are the middle terms in your binomial expansion not multiples of 3?  $(x+y)^3=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi, you're right! Thank you!

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout Can you please explain again why you don't have to think about the three last digits?